# Explode modifier size change over time?

Tags: modifiers, particles

When using a particle system, it is possible to change certain values (size, emission rate, etc.) over time using textures.

However, I cannot figure out how to do the same when using the "Quick Explode" feature. It seems that the preexisting "size" value in the particle system has no effect on the size of the smitherenated mesh.

How might I affect the size of the fragmented mesh using the particle system, specifically with reference to the texture-value manipulation system?

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Size" option in the explode modifier. This will make the particle size affect the size of the exploded fragments.